# Selecting all of the next table rows

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to select all of the next table rows with the class ".client_detail_level2" to show when I click a table row. I need the rows directly below the row that is clicked to show and no others with this same class. This is what I have so far.

```
$('tr.expandable td').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().next('.client_detail_level2').slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('collapsed');
 });
```

This currently shows the next closest row below but none of the others.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you looked at the example at http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `nextAll()` instead of `next()`